# Enabling Snapshots For All Maven Repositories

Tags: maven, nexus3

We have set up a local Maven repository for all development teams to use. It proxies external repositories and acts as the corporate artifact repository. We can control all access to external repositories through our local artifact manager.

We have distributed a `settings.xml` file that sends everything to that repository:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.2.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>internal-mirror</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <name>Pseudo repository to mirror external repositories.</name>
            <url>https://10.10.10.10/repository/maven/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>internal-mirror</id>
            <username>someusername</username>
            <password>somepassword</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

All pom files in all the projects only have `distrubutionManagement` section defined so they can publish releases and snapshots.

All is good and everything works great. Except for snapshots. Maven does not allow snapshots by default, so we have to specify `<snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>` somewhere.

Our goal is to enable snapshots with the least amount of code changes possible, preferably through the `settings.xml` file. We want to avoid having to update every `pom.xml` in every project, if possible.

What is the best way to enable snapshots in Maven using our local artifact repository?

Comment: you need to add to `settings.xml` remote repository with name `internal-mirror` and active profile as well, in that case maven will use that repository by default

Comment: You should configure your repository manager to handle that... and also you have to configure `settings.xml` accordingly...

Comment: Our repository handles snapshots currently. Maven won't retrieve them.
What do we add to the settings? We don't use profiles, so do we need to create one?
Can you be more specific?